# Xpath. Как добавить песню в vk.com?

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

Пытаюсь c помощью XPath добавить песню в мои аудиозаписи.
Проблема в том, что кнопка добавления трека появляется только при наведении мышкой на найденный трек. И код этой кнопки, получается генерируется динамически.

[image: vk page]

Я могу навести мышкой на найденный трек, но не могу нажать на эту кнопку. Неверный Xpath или просто webdriver не видит этот элемент?

```cs
    //Вводим в поиск "Say Say Say — Paul McCartney"
       var search = driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[@id='audio_search']");
         search.SendKeys("Say Say Say — Paul McCartney");
    // Выбираем первый найденный трек
       var track = driver.FindElementByXPath("(//div[@class='clear_fix _audio_pl audio_recoms_audios_block audio_w_covers']/div[@tabindex='0'])[1]");  

    // Попытка добавить трек в мои аудиозаписи
       actions.MoveToElement(track).MoveToElement(driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@class='audio_row__action audio_row__action_add _audio_row__action_add undefined' and @aria-label='Добавить в мою музыку']")).Click().Build().Perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Разделил запрос на две части. Так работает. Возможно можно по другому?

```cs
 var track = driver.FindElementByXPath("(//div[@class='clear_fix _audio_plaudio_recoms_audios_block audio_w_covers']/div[@tabindex='0'])[1]");
 actions.MoveToElement(track).Perform();

 driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@class='audio_row__action audio_row__action_add _audio_row__action_add undefined' and @aria-label='Добавить в мою музыку']").Click();
```

Comment: нет, невозможно т.к. в ВК эти кнопки не скрываются а именно тупо удаляются из кода страницы. Так что выходом является только двиганье виртуальной мышью.